# WPF buttons coverflow

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-4.0, coverflow

I have this XAML:
I create a `DataTemplate` for the class creditCard

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="creditTemplate"
                  DataType="DataTemplate:MonthBill.creditCard">
        <Button Content="{Binding creditCardNumber}"
                Click="OpenCardBillings" />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

In runtime i update the `DataContext` with a list of creditCard, and than i bind a itemscontrol to the datacontext, and it generates buttons for every item.

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="MainPanel"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource creditTemplate}"
              Margin="101,75,0,93"
              ClipToBounds="True"
              Width="408"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              UseLayoutRounding="False"
              ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            </VirtualizingStackPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

I want to create this buttons to a coverflow, I found tutorials for creating coverflow but not one that I colud create in runtime. any ideas?

Comment: You will need a custom-made panel that will arrange the items and applies some transformations to them. This panel should replace the `VirtualizingStackPanel` that you have now. And, don't forget to set `IsItemsHost="True"` to any panel that is in `ItemsPanelTemplate`.

Comment: do you have any xaml examples for this?

Comment: I've looked into this, and there seems to be a control that is called [ElementFlow](http://blog.pixelingene.com/2008/03/elementflow-added-to-fluidkit/) (part of the FluidKit) that will do what you need.